# How to form a Sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

In a group discussion, they give some topics and said to speak about that topic.
`consider the topic was tiger.`

I want to share it with my friends.. how can I form a sentence??

this below sentence is correct or not.
if its correct then explain me?

```
  we were asked to speak about tiger
```

Comment: Would one of the closevoters please post a link to an existing, answered question that would also answer this question? This is such a reasonable and natural question for a beginner to ask, it would be nice to give the OP the insight they're looking for, even if technically it's a proofreading question.

Comment: Why is this unclear?

Comment: It's a group discussion and *not all of you are going to speak!* In this context, you are just 'sharing' the topic in GD. So, better say -*We are **given** with the topic 'tiger'*.

Comment: "We are given with the topic 'tiger'" is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

> We were asked to speak about **tiger**.

This is incorrect. You can't "speak about tiger". It would have to be either this:

> We were asked to speak about **a tiger**.

to refer to a specific tiger—for example, if you're speaking of a single animal in a zoo exhibit.

Or you could say this:

> We were asked to speak about **tigers**.

to refer to tigers in general—for example, if you're speaking about behavior or diet.

---

Note also that I capitalized the first word `We` and added a period `.` at the end.

Comment: You could also say "We were asked to speak about the tiger", where "the tiger" refers to the concept / unspecified condition of tigers in general.